# The query processor could not start the necessary thread resources

Tags: multithreading, performance, sql-server-2008, parallel-processing

I am getting this error in SQL Server especially when there are many records inserted at the same time:

> The query processor could not start the necessary thread resources for parallel query execution

I tried Google search the problem to upgrade my SQL performance so that can avoid this error, and plenty of it suggests to set maxdrop on the query or the max degree of parallelism on SQL Server.

But how can I know how many the value of the maxdrop or max degree of parallelism I should set to?

And how do I check the maximum value of max degree of parallelism of my server can run?

If I change the max degree of parallelism of the server, means all the stored procedures will run following that setting, so will it affect other performance? Or do I just need to set the maxdrop on certain stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the server then click `FACETS` then choose/select `SERVER PERFORMANCE`